# Declare a global variable in class method

Tags: python, class, import, jupyter-notebook, global-variables

To control a pipetting Lab-Robot I want to create an importable Module that holds classes with pipetting patterns.
For this I defined classes like Sample, Reagents to be able to easily access and work with them with more readable code.

My Idea is to let the user be able to write a Dictionary of the style:

```
Samples = {
    'Sample1':{
        'ID':'Sample1',
        'volume' : 12,
        'location' : sample_plate['A1'],
        'concentration' : 166,
        'fmol' : 147,
        'nucleic_acid_type' : 0 
    },

    'Sample2': {
        'ID':'Sample2',
        'volume' : 11,
        'location': sample_plate['B1'],    #location on the robotsdeck
        'concentration' : 180,
        'nucleic_acid_type' : 0,
        'fmol':345                       #molarity of the sample 
    }
}
```

Then this Dictionary should be used to define variables in the Jupyter Notebook with the same name like the Samples Name (eg. Sample1, Sample2).

Those Variables are then instances of the class Sample with its method.

For example to access the volume of the sample and track it easier throughout the pipetting workflow I want the variable to have the attribute .volume to access its volume like eg.:

```
IN:
Sample1.volume 

Out:
12
```

I defined the class as seen in the following:

```
class Sample():
    global Sample_Variable_Dict
    Sample_Variable_Dict = {}

    global Sample_List
    Sample_List = []

    def __init__(self, ID='ID_missing', volume =  None, location= None , concentration= None, nucleic_acid_type= None, fmol= None):
        self.ID = ID
        self.volume = volume
        self.location = location
        self.concentration = concentration
        __nucleic_acid_types = ['RNA','RNA-DNA Hybrid', 'ss-DNA', 'ds-DNA']
        self.nucleic_acid_type = __nucleic_acid_types[nucleic_acid_type]
        self.fmol = fmol

    def Volume(self):
        print(str(self.volume)+'µl')

    def Concentration(self):
        print(str(self.volume) +'ng/µl')

    def FMOL(self):
        print(str(self.fmol)+'fmol')

    def Sample_Dicter(Sample_Dict):
        for sample, data in Sample_Dict.items():
            globals()[sample] = Sample(**data)
            Sample_Variable_Dict[globals()[sample]] = []
        for sample, data in Sample_Variable_Dict.items():
            print(sample.ID)
        return Sample_Variable_Dict
```

`Sample_Dicter()` is a method that should be able to use a Dictionary of the samples as input and then create the global variables of samples in the Notebook and also hold them all combined in the `Sample_Variable_Dict` to make them easier to iterate over etc.

When testing those methods in the notebook I used for testing the class or when copying the method into my working notebook, it works as intended and creates the global variables in that notebook.

**My Question: Why are the variables not created (accessible) in the working Noebook after I imported the module and called `Sample_Dicter(Samples)` with Samples being a Dictionary holding the samples attributes ?**

I import the method using

```
from Classes_Functions.class_Sample_Reagent import *
```

with `__init__.py` looking like this

```
__all__ = ['Classes']
```

---

**Possible Workaround**

I found a possible workaround to solve the Problem

```
for element, Liste in Sample_Variable_Dict.items():
print(element)
globals() [element.ID]  = element
```

But I wonder about the general Problem: **Is it possible to declare variable global through an imported Class Method?**

Comment: I am not sure you want to define a global variable inside the scope of the class. That would be a good place to declare a *class variable*.  Define the global variable outside the scope of the class and make sure you initialize it in just one place. You can later reference global variables from the class to initialize whatever components you want. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes I think I get it but that won´t solve the problem: I want a dictionary as Input that holds all the samples data and then initialize an object based on the dictionary data (strings & integers). The object should then be accessible like a normal variable and have all methods of class sample (so therefore be an object :D)

Comment: Are you familiar with this way of calling a method? It could be useful to call a method which has many (optional) arguments. Please excuse the poor formatting in a comment section.

    def foo(x, y):
        print("x=%s, y=%s" % (x,y))
    kwargs={'x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue')
    foo(**kwargs)

Comment: Thank you but that is what I did with the Sample_Dicter:    def Sample_Dicter(Sample_Dict):
        for sample, data in Sample_Dict.items():
            globals()[sample] = Sample(**data)
            Sample_Variable_Dict[globals()[sample]] = []